# Turning a list into a frequency dictionary

Tags: python

I am currently attempting to turn a list into a frequency dictionary. I am reading a file, separating the file into each individual words on a line and attempting to turn each word into its own frequency dictionary in order to find how many times it occurs. I was wondering how I would accomplish this. This is what I currently have:

```
with open(file, 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as fp:
    lines = fp.readlines()
    for row in lines:
        for word in row.split():
            print(word)
```

Currently, my program outputs a new word on each line. How would I make it so that the words are each their own dictionaries and can find the frequency of them?

Comment: as an aside, don't do `lines = fp.readlines()`. Just **loop directly over `fp`**

Answer (score 3):

The `Counter` class was designed for exactly this task.

```
from collections import Counter
with open(file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fp:
    counts = Counter(fp.read().split())
```

Now you can print `counts` and use its methods to get the most common words.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this for learning purposes (i.e. want to do it yourself, rather than using `Counter`, here is an example:

```
d = {} # Start with an empty ditctionary
with open(file, 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as fp:
    lines = fp.readlines()
    for row in lines:
        for word in row.split():
            d[word] = d.get(word,0) + 1 # Insert word into dictionary or update its value
```